# How to access propertices of a variable of an observable within angular template?

Tags: angular, rxjs

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public currentUser;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

app-header-navbar-user.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../shared/services/auth.service';

import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { constants } from '../../../../constants';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-navbar-user',
  template: `
  <div (click)="change()">CHANGEdisplayName</div>
  <div>{{ CUser$.displayName }}</div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent {
  public CUser$: Observable<any> =Observable.of(this.authService.currentUser);

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.currentUserObs$.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log("signInUser:ngOnInitIN:" + x);//always undefined here no matter what. 
    });
  }

  change() {
    if (!this.authService.currentUser)
           this.authService.currentUser = {};
    this.authService.currentUser['displayName'] = "YOMAN";//breaks here saying invalid property
  }
```

Comment: yes in service where `currentUser` and `CUser$` are declared but not in component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `?` (elvis) operator:

```html
<div>{{ (CUser$ | async)?.displayName }}</div>
```

Also, I see you are trying to update the value of `this.currentUser` and expecting the value of `this.CUser$` to change.

What you need is to make `this.CUser$` be a `BehaviorSubject` -- instead of a simple `Observable`-- and, to update it, call `.next(<new user>)`.

A complete component/example would be like:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>Display Name: "{{ (CUser$ | async)?.displayName }}"</h1>

  <button (click)="change()">CHANGE!</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private currentUser;

  // here, the value of this.currentUser is used as initial value of the observer CUser$
  // to change the value of CUser$, you must call CUser$.next(NEW VALUE).
  public CUser$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.currentUser);


  change() {
    this.currentUser = new User('Bob Nelson ONE'); // has no effect, just changes the currentUser

    this.CUser$.next(new User('Bob Nelson TWO')); // updates the CUser$
  }
}

class User  {
  constructor(public displayName: string) {}
}
```

[Plunker link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yAn1Nztxlujizl7768yW?p=preview).

Comment: `$` in front was a typo, updated the question, this didn't work actually

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? You get an error? No value is shown?

Comment: I also tried explicitly changing from component, instead of service,<div (click)="change()">CHANGEdisplayName</div>
  <div>{{ (CUser$ | async)?.displayName }}</div>`change() {
    if(!this.authService.currentUser)this.authService.currentUser={};
    this.authService.currentUser['displayName'] = "YOMAN";
  }`

Comment: But it doesn't . Do I need to move  `public CUser$: Observable<any> =Observable.of(this.currentUser);` from my service to component ? tried that too.

Comment: Actually, I think I get what your problem is. You are trying to update `this.CUser$`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Changing `Observable` to `BehaviorSubject` and `next()` did the trick. Thanks a lot. (Y) .  So isn't there a way to change using obserbable ?

Comment: A `BehaviorSubject` is a `Subject` that stores and replays the last (or initial) value. A `Subject` is both an `Observable` (so you can observe it) and an `Observer` (so you can push -- `.next()` -- values to it). So, in a sense, you are changing using `Observable`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use "as" syntax for this with ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="CUser$ | async as CUser"> {{ CUser.displayName }} </div>
```